# Ruby on Rails - send_file is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inline, sendfile

I wrote the following code.

```
def help_doc
  pdf_filename = File.join(Rails.root, "/public/doc.pdf")
  send_file(pdf_filename, :filename => "doc.pdf" :type => "application/pdf", :diposition => "inline")
end
```

It's working, but not as I want. I'd like to view in the browser the pdf, but it's doing download of the document.

I thought that just writing `:disposition => "inline"` and I could see on the browser the pdf.

Comment: You are missing a comma before the `:type` option. Is this a typo or is it your code?

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the content disposition. You have a typo in your code, deposition vs disposition, and you're missing a comma after filename.

Comment: It was just a mistake, when I wrote this question. In my code, is right, but keep wrong.

Comment: send_file actually doe snot really works well at all